# Android Sqlite query bind or column out of range

Tags: android, sqlite

I get this logcat output from my query below. I know that all of the columns are in the table I am trying to access. What does this error mean?

```
11-23 23:33:48.207: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16941): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x2cc688
```

#### Query:

```
Cursor value = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE open='1' AND country='?'", new String[]{countryID});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need quotes around the `?` in the query.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
Cursor value=checkDB.query(table,new String[]{"*"},"open=1 and country="'"+countryID+"'",null,null,null,null);
```